# How to stop functions from giving errors when using variables not defined in the function?

Tags: python, function

I am creating several experiments in python and have various functions which will be common across these experiments. I thus wanted to create a script only containing these functions which I could import at the beginning of the experimental script to avoid half of the script being taken up with 'generic setup lines'.

So far, I have created the functions and the script and can import them and use them. For example, in the following, I have a function which shows a blank screen which takes the duration I want (e.g., 4 seconds) and displays it on the window defined in the experimental script.

```
import functions 
win = visual.Window([1440,900], color=[-1,-1,-1], fullscr=True)
dur = 4
functions.blank_screen(duration=dur)
```

This all works fine but in the script containing the functions, there are several 'errors' the function uses the variable 'win' which is not defined in the function:

```
def blank_screen(duration):
    blank = TextStim(win, text='')
    blank.draw()
    win.flip()
```

But when I run the experimental script, as it is defined in the script, it all works. How can I get around this? I have this problem with several functions as a large majority uses variables which are defined in the experimental script and not in the functions. As I say, it all works but just annoys me that the script is covered in 'errors'!

I'd be greatly appreciative of any help, thank you!

Comment: Don't use variables not defined in the function.  Or, if you want to access a variable defined globally, tell the function that is the case by using `global`.

Comment: pass `win` as an argument to `blank_screen`, just like with `duration`. The script is absolutely right to throw an error, because `win` IS NOT defined, and a promise that you will define it in some other script is a very fragile one.

Comment: @Scott `global` won't make variables *from other modules* accessible.

Comment: @ScottHunter `global` won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass on the `win` you want blanked out as an argument to the `blank_screen` function:

```py
import functions 
win = visual.Window([1440,900], color=[-1,-1,-1], fullscr=True)
dur = 4
functions.blank_screen(duration=dur, win=win)
```

and

```py
def blank_screen(duration, win):
    blank = TextStim(win, text='')
    blank.draw()
    win.flip()
```

Comment: A `win=win` situation… (sorry, couldn't resist). More seriously, passing named arguments is superfluous here, positional arguments would do just fine.